# c# Http response empty when status code != 200-399

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to return a response depending on the status code.

At this moment, I just receive the response if the status code is between 200 and 399.

```
        public static void GetFileBrandingCSS(HttpContext context, string path)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
            string lines;
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension) && extension.Equals(".css"))
            {
                try
                {
                    lines = File.ReadAllText(path);
                    //context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    lines = "Couldn't find the file " + path ;
                    //context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lines = "The file " + path + " is not css.";
                //context.Response.StatusCode = 415;
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
            context.Response.Write(lines);
        }
```

If I uncomment the status code, in the code above, I only get the lines from the status code 200.

250 code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAkaN.png)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUMeU.png)

How can I always get a response?

400 code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMe50.png)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOfQq.png)

Comment: `Path.GetExtension(path)` <-- This is incorrect (even if it does seem to work): the `Path` class is meant for local filesystem paths, not for validating HTTP request resource paths.

Comment: @Dai It is validating local file system paths.